# Why do I seem to pee out more beer than I drink?

Tags: drinking

When going out for some beers, after a while, I seem to pee more than the amount of beer I drink. Is that true, and why is that?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about biology rather than beer.

Comment: Obviously, you should pee into the empty beer bottles to check this theory.

Comment: I really hope you're not actually peeing beer.

Comment: @waxeagle, I'd put this squarely in the middle of the beer/biology interest diagram. Assuming we have sufficient expertise to answer it here, it's relevance to the beer-drinking audience makes me think it's on-topic.

Comment: [The topicality of this question is being discussed on meta](http://meta.alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-much-do-we-want-to-get-into-biology).

Comment: Not only it a diuretic but it's also a toxin so your body wants it gone

Comment: Welcome to the Beer, Wine &Spirits SE site, Boogie Donelson. Some linked references would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: this gives me a great idea for my next tap handle. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Alcohol is a diuretic.  According to [this article](http://www.drinkaware.co.uk/check-the-facts/health-effects-of-alcohol/effects-on-the-body/why-does-alcohol-make-you-pee-more), 1 gram of alcohol will increase urine excretion by 10ml.  Combine that with [this CDC article](http://www.cdc.gov/alcohol/faqs.htm#standDrink) stating that a standard 12 ounce (354ml) beer has 14 grams of alcohol, your can expect to pee 494ml, or 16.75 ounces per 12 ounce bottle.

The graphic would be more accurate with you drinking three beers but peeing four.

Comment: This raises the importance of staying properly hydrated while drinking alcohol; the beer more you drink, the more dehydrated you're going to get.

Comment: it specifically decreases the production of ADH hormone
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasopressin

Answer (score 4):

Because beer is 95% water! Yes alcohol is a diuretic but if delivered with all this water, it is actually hydrating. If you would drink these huge glasses full of water you would urinate fearsomely as well.

So the best news ever is: beer is hydrating. There is scientific evidence for it [here](https://nutritionfacts.org/video/how-many-glasses-of-water-should-we-drink-a-day/) from 4:14 onwards. All before that is about the benefits of drinking water, yeah yeah.

[image]

Comment: Great answer on aviation and here. I will accept that answer as soon as I am off Suspension.